# Get multiple CSS properties with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know you can SET multiple css properties like so:

```
$('#element').css({property: value, property: value});
```

But how do I GET multiple properties with CSS?
Is there any solution at all?

Comment: You mean you want a map with a given set of CSS properties?

Comment: What do you mean by get multiple css properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own jQuery function to do this:
​

```
//create a jQuery function named `cssGet`
$.fn.cssGet = function (propertyArray) {

    //create an output variable and limit this function to finding info for only the first element passed into the function
    var output = {},
        self   = this.eq(0);

    //iterate through the properties passed into the function and add them to the output variable
    for (var i = 0, len = propertyArray.length; i < len; i++) {
        output[propertyArray[i]] = this.css(propertyArray[i]);
    }
    return output;
};
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6qfQx/1/ (check your console log to see the output)

This function requires an array to be passed in containing the CSS properties to look-up. Usage for this would be something like:

```
var elementProperties = $('#my-element').cssGet(['color', 'paddingTop', 'paddingLeft']);
console.log(elementProperties.color);//this will output the `color` CSS property for the selected element
```

Comment: Yeah, I would have done the same. I just wondered why this isn't already built in. Its just logical, since you can set a single property or set multiple properties. I have automatically assumed you can get a single property and even get multiple properties (would be by passing an array to .css()) but they just seem to forgot it.

Answer (score 14):

jquery's css method (as of 1.9) says you can pass an array of property strings and it will return an object with key/value pairs.

eg:

```
$( elem ).css([ 'property1', 'property2', 'property3' ]);
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Also, FWIW this method is faster than calling `.css()` multiple times... who woulda thought? ;) [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-multiple-css-get)

Comment: @peipst9lker, of course plain JS is faster than jQuery! Though, then you have to hack around browser support (currentStyle vs getComputedStyle). Tradeoffs...

Comment: As shown in my answer, working around browser support is trivially easy in this case. It's just as easy as the old `e = e || window.event` you used to need in manual event handling.

Answer (score 11):

Easiest way? Drop the jQuery.

```
var e = document.getElementById('element');
var css = e.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(e);
// now access things like css.color, css.backgroundImage, etc.
```